# Softether VPN Client - vpncmd - Two different MAC addresses for one virtual interface

Tags: ubuntu, mac-address, softether, dhcpcd

I've encountered strange MAC behaviour in my system - I've got 15 Linux Ubuntu machines with NetworkManager disabled and dhcpcd as DHCP client. Those devices connect to my SoftEther virtual HUB and as adresses are dynamically assigned I locate devices using MAC adresses.

For some reason MAC on SoftEther virtual interface changes - all my SoftEther MACs starts from "5E" but this one is "link/ether 16:35:96:be:0c:aa" despite fact that vpncmd NicList clearly says that the MAC should be "5E:59:11:CF:21:EC"

After rebooting that machine the mac goes back to what is should be - the "16:35" MAC will come back tho after about an day.

I've checked journalctl for logs related to this - have not encountered anything out of ordinary. I'm using SoftEther for some time and have never encountered this behaviour on both Ubuntu's and Debian's.

Would you have any idea why this is happening?

Best regards,